# Adding condition into target attribute for p:dataExporter to export two datatables in two different tabs one at a time to excel in primefaces

Tags: excel, primefaces, apache-poi

I have two radio buttons and used p:tabView with two tabs in my form. On click of first radio button first tab gets enabled and on click of second radio button second tab gets enabled. In both tabs there is one datatable. I want to export the datatable to excel format of both tabs one at a time. For this I am using  p:dataExporter. I am confused if conditional statement can be added in target for `p:dataExporter` as for first radio button I have to give the id of first tab table and for second radio button I have to give the id of second tab table. How can this be done ? My code is like this:

```
<h:form id="form" target="_blank">
<p:blockUI block="form" trigger="cmdView">
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/ajax-load.gif" />
</p:blockUI>
<p:panel header="#{text.form}">

    <h:panelGrid columns="5">
        <h:outputText for="console" value="SearchType" />

        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isBrief" value="#{customerMB.brief}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{customerMB.unCheckDetail}"
                update="isDetail tabview"></p:ajax>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

        <h:outputText value="#{text.Brief} " />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isDetail" value="#{customerMB.detail}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{customerMB.unCheckBrief}"
                update="isBrief tabview"></p:ajax>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="#{text.Detail}" />
    </h:panelGrid>


    <p:commandButton id="cmdView" icon="fa fa-search-plus"
        value="#{text.View}" actionListener="#{customerMB.generateList}"
        process="@this" update="@form" />


    <p:commandButton id="cmdExcel" value="#{text.Excel}"
        disabled="#{empty customerMB.formList}" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o"
        ajax="false">
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="form:tabview:table1"
            fileName="form" postProcessor="#{customerMB.postProcessXLS}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:panel>
<p:tabView id="tabview" activeIndex="#{customerMB.activeTab}">
    <p:tab title="#{text.CustReportBrief}" id="tab1"
        disabled="#{customerMB.detail}">

        <p:dataTable id="table1" var="tblA" scrollable="true"
            resizableColumns="true" value="#{customerMB.List1}"
            rowIndexVar="rowSn" paginator="true">
            <p:column headerText="#{text.SNo}" width="50">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblA.sn}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{text.MemberName}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblA.customerName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{text.Address}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblA.custAddress}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{text.CustReportDetail}" id="tab2"
        disabled="#{customerMB.brief}">

        <p:dataTable var="tblB" rowIndexVar="rowSn" scrollable="true"
            resizableColumns="true" value="#{customerMB.List2}" id="table2">
            <p:column headerText="#{text.SNo}" width="50px;">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblB.sn}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{text.Name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblB.customerName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{text.Address}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblB.custAddress}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{text.Contact}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblB.custContact}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{text.Email}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tblB.custEmail}" />
            </p:column>



        </p:dataTable>

    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did my own way and it's simple too. I defined string variable to hold the table id in custmerMB and according to the radio button selected i set the value in that variable.
The code is like this:

```
private String tblToExport;

public String getTblToExport() {
    return tblToExport;
}

public void setTblToExport(String tblToExport) {
    this.tblToExport = tblToExport;
}

public void unCheckDetail() {

    if (isBrief == true) {
        tblToExport=":form:tabview:table1";

}

public void unCheckBrief() {

    if (isDetail == true) {
        tblToExport=":form:tabview:table2";

    } 
}
```

and excel button code is:

```
<p:commandButton id="cmdExcel" value="#{text.Excel}"
    disabled="#{empty customerMB.formList}" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o"
    ajax="false">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{customerMB.tblToExport}"
        fileName="form" postProcessor="#{customerMB.postProcessXLS}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem before, I solved this with two undisplayed `commandButton`s with dataExporter inside and triggered it with a `commandButton`.

```
    <p:commandButton id="cmdExcel" value="#{text.Excel}"
        disabled="#{empty customerMB.formList}" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o"
        onstart="document.getElementById('btn1').click()" 
        oncomplete="document.getElementById('btn2').click()"/>
    <p:commandButton id="btn1" ajax="false" style="display: none;">
        <p:dataExporter target="table1" type="xls" fileName="table1"/>
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton id="btn2" ajax="false" style="display: none;">
        <p:dataExporter target="table2" type="xls" fileName="table2"/>
    </p:commandButton>
```